# What does hello mean here in this conversation?

Tags: meaning-in-context, informal-language

Here Two people taking part in conversation.

> A: When was USA got independence ?
>
> B: Search in google, **hello**.

What does hello mean here in this conversation?

Comment: We need more context and more of the conversation. There is definitely something wrong here as the first sentence is not grammatically correct.

Comment: Where did you find this conversation?

Comment: *Hello* is generally used to greet someone or to attract attention. However, spoken exaggeratedly, it can also be used to mean "Wake up! What is the matter with you?"

Comment: In the context above, I'm imagining it being said in a condescending, drawn out tone of voice.